# Black Screen After Logoff

Tags: 12.04, login-screen

Every time I logoff from Ubuntu 12.04 I get a black screen. If I logon again as if I could really see what I'm doing, the screen returns to normal. This doesn't happen with other two users on the same machine, with both of them I can logoff withouth problems. Any clues?

Comment: What graphic card do you have? Did you updat the drivers?

Comment: Thankx four your comment, Lucio. I have an integrated Intel GPU, just as rat2000 below. I will try his suggestion as soon as I can.

Comment: So far, I have not been able to resolve this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done on my laptop. I have a integrated Intel GPU.

> #### Force Pipe A Quirk
>
> This problem typically exhibits itself on Intel graphics hardware
> (most particularly i855) by locking up the machine when closing the
> lid.  The fix for this issue is to quirk your card to force enabling
> Pipe A. If you suspect you're having this bug, try setting this option
> in your xorg.conf:
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>     ..
>     Option "ForceEnablePipeA" "true"
> EndSection
> ```

Fore more reference visit the source of the above quote:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Quirks#Force_Pipe_A_Quirk

There are some possible fixes about ATI and nVidia.

Comment: Rat2000: I use an Intel GPU as well. But my system doesn't use an xorg.conf file. Should I create one just for this or is there another way to force enabling Pipe A?

Comment: Have you search in "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"??? do you use bumblebee??? I know you can make a xorg.conf file manually, but i don't really know how.

Comment: Rat2000: there is no Xorg.conf file in that location, I think Ubuntu does not use that file anymore since 09.04, but indeed you can create one if needed. Thus, my question for a workaround. Thankx for your quick reply, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Any updates? I"ve been trying to use this quirk, but the instruction is very unclear. So do I just need to paste the above quote into my newly created `xorg.conf`?

Comment: @Rat2000 I tried this on my ThinkPad X201i and my boot got stuck at Broke pipe: cannot write bytes. I had to boot into recovery mode and delete `xorg.conf`.